# HTML Image Email displaying on Outlook Desktop but not on Outlook Mobile

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have an email html template, while it displays perfectly on Outlook Desktop (an other mail apps), it doesn't on Outlook Mobile:

```
<!--[if mso]>                    
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 170px;">
                        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" />
                            <v:textbox style="v-text-anchor:bottom" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                <div style="position: relative; text-align: center;">
                                    <font color="#ffffff">
                                        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 20px; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 50px;">
                                            <p style="color: white">&nbsp;&nbsp;Image Title</p>
                                    </font>
                                </div>                                            
                            </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>

<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <tr>
        <div style="padding:0;Margin:0;position:relative;font-size:14px">
        <img class="adapt-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt title width="560">
        <p style="position: absolute; bottom: -30px; left: 16px; color: white; font-size: 50px">&nbsp;Image Title</p>                     
        </div>
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

I'm suspicious it can be fixed with the <!--[if mso]>  tag, but haven't been able to find a source for Mobile vs Desktop.
(image is not being displayed on Outlook Mobile but it is on Outlook Desktop)

Thanks

Comment: A rather simplistic question, but just in case - have you checked that images are set to be shown on the mobile outlook?

Comment: Have you first of all verified that outlook mobile is configured to _allow_ loading of external images?

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, it allows / shows external images.